# Access Python dict with wildcard key element

Tags: python, dictionary, wildcard

Given the dict (fragment below), the structure will always be the same, but the key-name  `'private'` may change name, and I have no independent way to know what will be the value of `'private'` part of the key.

```
json = simplejson.loads(open('servers.list', 'r').read())
for server in json['servers']:
{
    "servers": [
        {
            "addresses": {
                "private": [
                    {
                        "addr": "10.2.198.244",
                        "version": 4
                    },
                    {
                        "addr": "10.4.189.211",
                        "version": 4
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

How do I reference `'addr'`?

in general, this will work, but it is not a way to replace `'private'` with wildcard:

```
addr0 = server.get('addresses').get(‘private')[0].get('addr’)
```

Comment: `json['servers']['assresses'].values()` should ust tell you the values right?

Comment: @ssm : the value of `servers` is a list, not a dict

Comment: My bad! Go a little confused with the format. I gestt it will have to be `json[server]['assresses'].values()` after the for loop then ....

Answer (score 1):

For the one off selection of address 0 in this very contrived example:

```
>>> addr0 = json['servers'][0]['addresses'].values()[0][0]['addr']
>>> addr0
'10.2.198.244'
```

More generally it is difficult to say.

To what does the key `private` change? Would it be `public` by any chance? It looks like there could be other types of address (e.g. public) that might be present in the `addresses` dict. You can not assume a particular order of keys in the dictionary, which means that you can't rely on `dict.values()` returning the private addresses at list index 0. It is unpredictable without a reliable key.